# ActionToggle image not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am implementing `ActionTogglebutton` to show drawer.though drawer are showing on click of toggle button but image or nothing is shown on toggle button position

Here is my code

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.drawable.kooveicon) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Closed");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Browse Items");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

    }
};
```

Comment: do setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

Comment: still not showing image it is working properly but not showing image .

Answer (score 0):

Update your code exactly like below:

```
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

and add another method **onPostCreate()** in your class [this is drawer indicator animation]

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Hope this helped!